# Dropdown Menu to change URL resets page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Okay so I have a table with information pulled from a JSON and I want to be able to filter what is shown in the table based on the URL.  So, I added some code that will change the URL when the dropdown menu is changed (to each of the different filters).  It works to change the URL (it becomes `example.com?filter=memories` or `example.com?filter=booklet` or whichever filter is selected).  The only thing is instead of following through and going to the filter function that it's supposed to go to, it instead just kind of resets the page and nothing shows up.  There is no error in the console so I'm not sure if I'm just missing something obvious or what.  Here is the code that does the filtering and changes the URL:

```
function getUrlParameter(changeURL)
{
    window.document.location.href=changeURL; 
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == null) 
        {
            filterAll();
        }
        else{
            var theChoice = sParameterName[1];
            filterChoice(theChoice);
        }
    }
}   


function filterChoice(choice){
    if(choice.value=="all"){
        clearTable();
        filterAll();
    }
    else if (choice.value=="booklet"){
        bounds = "Booklet";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value=="frontier"){
        bounds = "Frontier";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value=="fs"){
        bounds = "FS";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "ft"){
        bounds = "FT";
        clearTable();       
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "home"){
        bounds = "Home";
        clearTable();       
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "idx"){
        bounds = "IDX";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "login"){
        bounds = "Login";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "memories"){
        bounds = "Memories";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "search"){
        bounds = "Search";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "signInPage"){
        bounds = "SignInPage";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "signOut"){
        bounds = "SignOut";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
    else if(choice.value == "temple"){
        bounds = "Temple";
        clearTable();
        filterByTimerName(bounds);
    }
}
```

I would REALLY appreciate any sort of help I can get!!  I added some pictures for clarification.
[image: What it is supposed to look like]
[image: What it DOES look like]
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I'll answer my own question since I figured it out.  Basically what I did was use a function that looked at the URL and parsed it to see what the extension "filter" was.  Then I have a switch statement to do something based on that filter.  The URL extension gets changed using an onclick event listener.  This is probably not the most effective way to do this, but it worked for my situation!